# Does Google Chrome store browsing history on their servers?

Tags: server, chrome

Does Google Chrome store browsing history on their servers? I think, if for example I use private browsing, Chrome can still log my activity.

Comment: "On their servers" - what do you mean by that? There are several different things you could mean.

Comment: Probably on Google servers but I don't really know, so I say "their". I mean, I want to know if my browsing history can be externally exposed by other people than me, excluding my ISP.

Comment: If you read the page that displays on the Private Browsing, it says: Chrome won’t save the following information:
Your browsing history. What more are you asking, then?

Comment: @schroeder goggle probably does save what you search.Their whole business model is based on "keywords".

Comment: @Vipul Nair I also think in the same way, but I'm interested if for example I use DuckDuckGo and Chrome can still log my history locally, so, I'm currious if it also stored externally.

Comment: @LiudvikasZubitskis you could answer it yourself if you read google chrome privacy aggreement.I dont think anyone here would have.

Comment: You're right, I didn't think about that before. Thanks.

Comment: I just remembered why this question came to my head. Look at Shaurya Singh's answer. https://www.quora.com/Can-websites-access-my-real-IP-address-when-using-TOR-with-bridge Do you think, he's not right?

Comment: @LiudvikasZubitskis The question you're asking and the question they're answering are *worlds* apart. Consider revising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

If you're logged into chrome, and not using incognito, then sure.

If you're not logged in to chrome, they store a list of all the sites you've visited through their tracking cookies.

Assuming you're using incognito, there are lots of ways people track you. Here are a few.

If you're using private browsing, there is not local history, and there is no tracking cookies (unless you don't close the private browser, and there is a tracking cookie that maps all the sites you visit while using the private browser. So, if you login with gmail, then visit p..nhub, then google probably mapped you to that url and then yeah, you're in their records.

If you're using your ISP's DNS, then your ISP can see all of the host names you resolve. They also know your name, address, and credit card number. So if you visit p..nhub from your ISP, they have a record that you went there. They don't know anything beyond that if the sites you visit are HTTPS, but if they are HTTP, then they can see the pages you visit too.

Comment: Thanks! As you said, cookies can track only sites. But for example, I was looking to buy the new speakers in the multiple websites and after that, full fb was full of speaker adds. So, is it trick of Google or something else?

Comment: some of the tracking cookies are javascript apps that run in your browser and can fingerprint your device (screen resolution, ip address, window size, operating system version, chrome version, etc). These factors "fingerprint" your computer and can be used instead of cookies.